# Orderby in Rails association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-order-by, polymorphic-associations

I have the following tables

```
One is Bookmarking Table has (activity_id as foreign key)
 Table 2 - Activity has(item_id as foreign key..)
 Table 3 - ItemCache has (id,item_id,item_type, created_at...)
 Table 4 - Blog has(id,title,user_id,created_at...)
 Table 5 - Tweet has (id,title,user_id,created_at..)
```

Item table has the actual items blogs, tweet saved
And when this item is bookmarked, activity is saved

Now i am trying to fetch all the bookmarked items of a user
which i fetched using

```
current_user.bookmarks
```

And now i want to order these bookmarked items based on the items created_at desc

I tried writing scope in bookmark model as

```
scope :ordered, :joins => :activity, :order => "activities.created_at DESC"
```

the above sorts based on activities created at

**How to order these bookmarked items based on item cached created_at**

Suggest please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
scope :ordered, :include => [{ :activity => :item_cache }], :order => "item_caches.created_at desc"
```

Above code assumes that:

```
bookmark.rb
  belongs_to :activity

activity.rb
  belongs_to :item_cache
```